# Creating a status attribute for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, attributes

I want to create a `status` attribute for my `Task`model that would indicate where it is in a three part progress in this order: `open` => `in-progress` => `complete`. It would work in a way similar to how an Amazon package is delivered: ordered => shipped => delivered. I was wondering what would be the best way to setup this attribute. I may be wrong but creating three separate boolean attributes seemed sort've redundant. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails 4 has an built in [enum macro](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). It uses a single integer column and maps to a list of keys.

```
class Order
  enum status: [:ordered, :shipped, :delivered]
end
```

The maps the statuses as so:  `{ ordered: 0, shipped: 1, delivered: 2}`

It also creates scopes and "interrogation methods".

```
order.shipped?
Order.delivered.all
```

It will also map the enum values when writing queries with hash arguments:

```
Order.where(status: [:shipped, :delivered])
```

Comment: However depending on your use you might want to move up to using an actual state machine like @nesiseka recommended.

Comment: `status` would presumably be saved as an integer with a a default value of `0` correct?

Comment: You mention using the aasm gem "depending on your use". Care to elaborate?

Comment: +1 for using a simple emum. Avoiding the use of too many gems for too many things keeps your project simple, clean, and independent.

Comment: @CarlEdwards depending on how many model status you want to manage, and how complicated the transitions between the status are. 
Stick to simple things if your logic is simple

Comment: I think I'll use an enum in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [aasm gem](https://github.com/aasm/aasm). It has aasm_states for models, callback functionality etc.